# R wont assign a value to a variable, but doesn't throw an error

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

When I run this code I want it to change the rows in the data set that dont have a probability over 60% to be changed to unassigned. I am accessing the variable the correct way because you can see it printed in the output, the issue is with assigning the variable.

```
rowsCat <- array(get('Email Category', envir = as.environment(dataset2) , mode = "any", inherits = TRUE))
rowsCapCallProb <- array(get('Scored Probabilities for Class "Capital Call"', envir = as.environment(dataset1) , mode = "any", inherits = TRUE))
rowsDistroProb <- array(get('Scored Probabilities for Class "distribution"', envir = as.environment(dataset1) , mode = "any", inherits = TRUE))
rowsFinnancialProb <- array(get('Scored Probabilities for Class "Finnancial Document"', envir = as.environment(dataset1) , mode = "any", inherits = TRUE))
    
data.set = rbind(dataset1)

checkProb <- function(count) {
  print("===================================================================")
  print(paste("Evaluating Probabilities on Row: ", count))
   
  
  #Check to see if Probabilities are over 60%
  if(rowsCapCallProb[[count]] > .60 | rowsDistroProb[[count]] > .60 | rowsFinnancialProb[[count]] > .60){
    print(paste("A probable Score was located for Row: ",count))
  } else {
    print(paste("Attempting to assign 'Unassigned' to Row: ",count, " : ", data.set$ScoredLables[[count]]))
    
    #\/ Issue is here in the assignment \/
    data.set$ScoredLables[[count]] <- "Unassigned"    
  }
  
  print("===================================================================")
}


for (rowCat in rowsCat) {
    checkProb(count)
        
    count = count+1
}
```

[Output Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH1Tp.png)
[Basic Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4upK.png)

Comment: Changes made inside a function are local to the function. If you want `checkProb` to modify a data frame, you should pass that data frame to the function as an argument, modify it inside the function, and have the function `return()` the modified data frame. You then assign the result, e.g., `modified_data <- checkProb(data = data.set, count = ...)` or overwrite the original with `data.set <- checkProb(data = data.set, count = ...)`.

Answer (score -2):

Check the scoping inside your function. If you want to (over)write a variable to the global environment from inside a function, use `<<-`, not `<-`. See the below example:

```
x <- 1

samp_fun1 <- function(){

  x <- 2  

}

samp_fun2 <- function(){

  x <<- 3

}


samp_fun1() #x still = 1
samp_fun2() #x should equal 3
```

Comment: Any answer mentioning `<<-` should warn of the dangers. This is a way to write a function that is extremely hard to generalize as it can *only* be used on variables named `x`, that will be difficult to use inside other functions, and most other R users won't want to touch because it behaves unlike 99% of R functions.

Comment: "the issue is with assigning the variable"; this answers the question exactly whether or not you think it is dangerous or makes your function less useful for others.

Comment: Yes, it does answer the question exactly as stated. A good answer provides additional context, as appropriate, especially when the premise of the question seems flawed.  See, for example, [discussions of the XY problem on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/173584). (BTW, I didn't downvote your answer, I just commented. I assume the downvotes are from those that agree with me and +1'ed my comment. I'd happily upvote your answer if you also include appropriate words of caution and presented the usual alternative.)